# Accessing SessionState from a background thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, session-variables

I've an asp.net page which executes a long running task. So I execute the task in a separate thread and poll the page regularly to check for the status.

```
public partial class ResultPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
      {
         ProcessItems(parameters);
      }));
      t.Name = "ThreadInfoPathProcess";
      t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
      t.Start();
   }

   private void ProcessItems(Parameters params)
   {
      //
      //some code
      //

      //save the result in session and take it from another page
      lock (this.Session.SyncRoot)
         this.Session[resultid] = result;
   }
}
```

But when I access the session from some another page I'm getting the session variable as null. What could be the problem here?

Comment: What is the order of calls of the pages?

Comment: The page has a asp timer control which postbacks to the page and checks the status of the thread. The thread is started from the page and updates the result to the session state. In the timer_tick I check whether the thread has finished running and I redirect to another page. From the new page I read the session state to get the result given by the thread and manipulate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is creating windows service where you will schedule your long running processes via remote calls from the web application (WCF - can be local over named pipes). Then your timer will pool the page which will in turn either pool the windows service or check some status record with the result in the database.